# is .htaccess + mod_rewrite the right way to manage the permission for epub-files (epub-shop)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permissions

i want to deliver epub-file via online-shop.
is .htaccess + mod_rewrite the right way to manage the permission for epub-files (epub-shop)?

```
# .htaccess in epub-folder
# sends every file to "download.php"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) download.php?file=$1
```

download.php manage the licence part. is there any hack/trick to get the files without the licence? Directly via deeplink?

thanks for help!

Comment: We cannot say with the little information you give. Depends on where you store your documents and how your "licence part" looks like. Also keep in mind that once someone downloaded a document, he is in possession and can do with it whatever he wants...

Comment: thanks! the epub files are stored in "epub". the licence part only check if the user has permisson. when have permission, i use readfile($file) to deliver the epub.

Comment: What I meant is: if the content of that storage area (the `ebug` folder) is delivered by apache directly, for example because it is inside the document root, then certainly you can download files directly. We do not know your setup, only you can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually do access control via the directives in mod_authz_host. [This document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) outlines how you can do this.

If you have access to the main configuration file of Apache (httpd.conf or something alike), I would recommend adding a directory section to it. Afterwards you need to restart your Apache.

```
<Directory /a/b/c/epub/>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

`Order` tells in which order directives are processed. `Deny from all` denies direct access from everyone.

Otherwise, you can add a .htaccess in the epub directory, then add the same 2 directives to it without the directory block.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have access to the main configuration file of Apache. Is there an other way? Without editing the conf.

Comment: By not stopping half-way through the answer.